# How to add 5 images from gallery to diiferent Horizontal scrollable ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

please help me to solve this question: How to select  5 images from gallery and add 5 images to different ImageView dynamically in android   ?

Answer (score 0):

May be [This link can solve your answer](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/)

1. Link shows create your own gridview [Custom adapter with `ImageView and Checkbox`] 
   And then set the `Adapter` by extending `BaseAdapter`.
2. You can ask in detail if you can't get the flow and logic behind the demo THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the list of images to PagerAdapter .

see this http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-implementing-viewpager-into-gridview-tutorial/